# Ionic 3: Getting value from PlayStore link

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 app and I want to set some variable inside it based on the download link from Playstore.
For example, `http://linktoplaystore.com/app?account=4` would set the account variable inside my app to be 4. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The only way would be Firebase Dynamic links to achieve this I would say. But the links have to be created somewhere (manually or in code). Take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/. The Ionic plugin for this is still in beta though: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-dynamic-links/

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/  this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Alex is this query resolved? take advantage of losing your points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work using Firebase Dynamic Links.

After I've setup my app in the Firebase console, I manually created a link which looks like this:

```
https://myapp.page.link/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ionicframework.myapp?account4
```

In my Ionic app, I've installed and configured `Firebase Dynamic Links` plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-dynamic-links/

Then, inside `app.component.ts`, after the platform is initialized, I use this code:

```
firebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink().subscribe((res: any) => {
 let link = res;
}, err => {
  alert(err);
});
```

The link will be a JavaScript object that looks like this:

```
{"deepLink":"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ionicframework.couriermanagerclient1234?account4","clickTimestamp":1535449992657,"minimumAppVersion":0}
```

From here, I can parse the result and extract the account parameter from inside the `deepLink` property

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in code by parsing and defining an array

```
private urlParameters: Array<any> = [];

if (YOURURLVARIABLE.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    let splitURL = document.URL.split("?");
    let splitParams = splitURL[1].split("&");
    let i: any;
    for (i in splitParams){
        let singleURLParam = splitParams[i].split('=');
        let urlParameter = {
        'name': singleURLParam[0],
        'value': singleURLParam[1]
    };
    this.urlParameters.push(urlParameter);
    }
}

this.urlParamID = navParams.get('account').value;
```

Comment: Well, the main problem is with how to get the installation URL inside the app

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible from the Playstore, but from an external source of your own you could access in app functions via Deeplinks. See https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/ for more information.

```
this.deeplinks.route({
    '/account/:accountId': AccountPage
}).subscribe(match => {
    console.log(match.$args);
}, nomatch => {
    console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse `link` in JavaScript to get the required value

*Code Snippet*

```
var link = "http://linktoplaystore.com/app?account=4";
var variable = link.split('?')[1].split('=')[1];
```

> Also, you should open an API to send this link from server, so you don't need to push app-update in case of any changes in the link.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But how can I get the installation link inside the app?

Comment: unfortunately, there is no way (as of yet) to get the link from the app stores, as mentioned above you will have to maintain & send this link from your own server

Comment: This method assumes account is the first parameter. You should use a key based function to get the account. If playstore adds other parameters like language= then your array keys will be off.

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be Firebase Dynamic links to achieve this (as stated in my comment earlier).

Dynamic links **can** survive the app installation process. And because of that, you can use the parameters. But the links have to be created somewhere (manually or in code).

Take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/. The Ionic plugin for this is still in beta though: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-dynamic-links/

Comment: Hi Alex, thank u.. Could u place how to do so. I knew how to subscribe, but do I need to create the link on firebase console? Then how to send the dynamic link?