# how to pass parameter to android playstore to be retrieved when my ionic 3 app is installed

Tags: ionic3

I want to pass a parameter(userId="Derrick") to play the store's link of my ionic 3 apps and retrieve it after app installation.

I have tried many ideas:
1- Firebase Dynamic Links plugins; I was not able de manage firebase console side(google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist). I have not found a working example. (according to this question [Ionic 3: Getting value from PlayStore link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893126/ionic-3-getting-value-from-playstore-link))
2- Google Analytics plugin; with getVar, I have no result
3- TealiumInstallReferrer plugin; no way (according to this questionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466443/how-to-use-app-links-to-pass-parameter-to-android-playstore-to-be-retrieved-when)
4- App Preferences; 
5- I have also tried to use a third party URL to store parameter in SQLite but it was impossible to write inside SQLite of mobile phone from a website
6- I have tried many propositions but I have no solution.

Answer (score 0):

My **Holy Grail** is **Branch.io**. It gives me exactly what I need to resolve my problem. There are two main links which help me to solve my problem:

1. This link https://docs.branch.io/apps/cordova-phonegap-ionic/ helps me to create manual links with parameters as need and I was able to retrieve thus parameters in my source code after apps installation.
2. This other link https://docs.branch.io/apps/deep-linking-api/ helps me to create dynamic links at runtime using rest API.